# Invalid register eip?

Tags: gdb, x86-64, disassembly, eip

I am debugging a c program with gdb in linux terminal, I disassembled it and ran it, then tried to find the memory address the the EIP register. This is what happened:

(gdb) i r eip
Invalid register `eip'

Why does it say that my eip register is invalid?

Comment: Is it a 64-bit program? If so, it's rip, not eip.

Comment: Yes that's it thank you I had no idea they were different names.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is it a 64-bit program? If so, it's rip, not eip.

Comment: Note that `gdb` allows you to refer to the program counter using `$pc`. This will work on both 32 and 64 bit, and also on other architectures.

Comment: So what to do if I want eip instead rip?

Comment: @DeepJadia You can't really choose because it's ip in 16-bit mode, eip in 32-bit mode and rip in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your program's architecture the register can change:

- 16 bit - `ip`
- 32 bit - `eip`
- 64 bit - `rip`